# nested min-height does not work

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed size absolutely positioned area with scrollbars containing variable sized content.

Now I need to wrap content in two divs that are at least as large as area but expand to fit content.

```
<div id="area">
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="inner">
            <div id="content">content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Requirements:

1. They need to expand, so their height must be set to auto.
2. In order to fill container their minimum size must be 100%

Therefore I've tried following CSS (full example in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5aj6k/4/)):

```
#area {
    /* defined outside */
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: scroll;
}

#outer, #inner {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

It does work for `#outer` but has no effect on `#inner`. How can I fix it ?

**UPDATE**
I'm only interested in Chrome if that helps.

Also, I can accept that it might not be possible if pointed to some authoritative source with explanation.

**UPDATE 2**

So I've analyzed CSS specs and concluded that my requirements can't be met:

1. For min-height to work it must be absolutely positioned or it's containing block height must not depend
   on content height [CSS2(10.7)](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-min-height)
2. I need autosizing so neither `#inner` nor `#outer` can be absolutely positioned. This means that
   containing block must have specified height.
3. Therefore `#outer` can't be containing block of `#inner`. This leaves me with `#area`.
4. According to [CSS2(10.1)](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details) that's only possible for `#inner` when element is positioned absolutely which
   conflicts with my objective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#inner` using a percentage height means it is based off of the height of its parent `#outer`, which is not specified as an exact `%` or `px`:

```
#area {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#outer,#inner {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#outer {
    height:100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[jsFiddle provided here](http://jsfiddle.net/YNqkj/2/), which shows with color that `#inner` gets the full height of `#outer`.

I also took a few liberties. I set your `#area` CSS to be a more proper full height/width setup, and i made your scrolling component `#outer` instead of `#area`, since `#inner` will be the content that overflows it.

Comment: This locks the height of `#outer` which fails requirement 2. I need it to expand and have scrolling on `#area`.

Comment: While this does not solve my problem, you were right that `#outer` needs exact height for relative sizing of `#inner` to work (see UPDATE 2 above).

Answer (score 0):

If you change `min-height: 100%;` to `height: 100%;` it will work.

Comment: Not if #content overflows (see above).

Answer (score 0):

Your min-height should be based on `px` not in `%` atleast thats how I got my problem fixed. just use a reasonable `pixel-height`

In this way inner will always be as big as outer.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure i have correctly understood the question, what should expand inner or content ?

Assuming you want inner expanded to fill outer.
As mentioned you also need a height of 100%, and a postion of absolute on inner

and then depending on what is supposed to scroll either on inner or content

```
#outer {
background: red;
position: static;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
}
#inner {
background: blue;
position: absolute;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
height:100%;
overflow:auto;
}
#content {
height: 200px;
background-color:yellow;
overflow:auto;
}
```

[example here - with content, which scrolls](http://jsfiddle.net/5aj6k/4/)

Answer (score -1):

```
#outer, #inner {
    height:100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This does not expand to fit content if you shrink window and cause #content to overflow (requirement 2).